# How do I Merge/Concatenate values into a new node using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, concatenation, xslt-1.0

I am just starting out using XSLT and need help merging/concatenating values into a new node. The examples below so the current XSLT/XML data.

Example XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" />        
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Order xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<OrderId><xsl:value-of select="/Order/OrderId"/></OrderId>
      <OrderLines>
        <xsl:for-each select="/Order/OrderLines/OrderLine">
            <OrderLine>
              <OrderLineId><xsl:value-of select="OrderLineId"/></OrderLineId>
            </OrderLine>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </OrderLines>
    </Order>
</xsl:template>
```

Example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Order xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<OrderId>1</OrderId>
<OrderLines>
    <OrderLine>
        <OrderLineId>v1</OrderLineId>
    </OrderLine>
</OrderLines>
```

**My question is how I would go about merging/concatenating OrderId and OrderLineId into a new node.** For instance, I am trying to get the value to display as such:

OrderId - OrderLineId

or

Order 1 - v1

If there are multiple order lines, then I would need it to be formatted as such:

OrderId - OrderLineId, OrderLineId, OrderLineId

or

Order 1 - v1, v2, v3

Example XSLT below:

```
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" />        
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Order xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <OrderId><xsl:value-of select="/Order/OrderId"/></OrderId>
      <OrderLines>
        <xsl:for-each select="/Order/OrderLines/OrderLine">
            <OrderLine>
              <OrderLineId><xsl:value-of select="OrderLineId"/></OrderLineId>
            </OrderLine>
            <OrderLine>
              <OrderLineId><xsl:value-of select="OrderLineId"/></OrderLineId>
            </OrderLine>
            <OrderLine>
              <OrderLineId><xsl:value-of select="OrderLineId"/></OrderLineId>
            </OrderLine>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </OrderLines>
    </Order>
</xsl:template>
```

Example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Order xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<OrderId>1</OrderId>
<OrderLines>
    <OrderLine>
        <OrderLineId>v1</OrderLineId>
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine>
        <OrderLineId>v2</OrderLineId>
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine>
        <OrderLineId>v3</OrderLineId>
    </OrderLine>
</OrderLines>
```

Overall, the new node in the XML needs to simply be: OrderId - OrderLineId and if there are multiple OrderLineId's, then to have those separated by a comma and then a space.

Expected XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Order xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<OrderId>1</OrderId>
<OrderLines>
    <OrderLine>
        <OrderLineId>v1</OrderLineId>
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine>
        <OrderLineId>v2</OrderLineId>
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine>
        <OrderLineId>v3</OrderLineId>
    </OrderLine>
</OrderLines>
<OrderNumbers>Order 1 - v1, v2, v3</OrderNumbers>
</Order>
```

Again, I am brand new to this and am not really sure how to go about this. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Order">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()"/>
        <OrderNumbers>
            <xsl:text>Order </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="OrderId" />
            <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="OrderLines/OrderLine">
                <xsl:value-of select="OrderLineId" />
                <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </OrderNumbers>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```